# Almond branch or watcher?

Tags: exegesis, jeremiah

What does Jeremiah 1:11 mean with regards to almond branch? The Lord’s response about watching is not clear with regards to almond trees.

> 11 And the word of the LORD came to me, saying, "Jeremiah, what do you
>   see?" And I said, "I see an almond branch." 12 Then the LORD said to
>   me, "You have seen well, for I am watching over my word to perform
>   it." - Jeremiah 1:11-12 ESV

Most commentators like Matthew Henry would posit some trait of almonds tree. Calvin and at least one other would prefer a “watcher” with reference to the root of the word being Hebrew verb ; because the Lords response is of watching instead of tree traits.

NIV

> 11 The word of the Lord came to me: “What do you see, Jeremiah?”   “I
>   see the branch of an almond tree,” I replied.   12 The Lord said to
>   me, “You have seen correctly, for I am watching b to see that my word
>   is fulfilled.”

Douay-Rheims Bible

> And the word of the Lord came to me, saying: What seest thou,
>   Jeremias? And I said: I see a rod watching.

Young’s literal translation.

> here is a word of Jehovah unto me, saying, 'What art thou seeing,
>   Jeremiah?' And I say, 'A rod of an almond tree I am seeing.

The word is rendered "a rod of almond" by the Septuagint, the Arabic version, and Theodotion; and also by Piscator, Drusius, Grotius, and Blayney; and "the rod of the watcher" by Sym., Aq., and the Vulgate The latter is no doubt more suitable in a translation.

> It should be, "I see the rod, "or the staff, "of a watcher."  Let us
>   grant that the almond is intended; yet the tree may be called
>   watchful, according to what etymology requires, and also the sense of
>   the passage, as all must see. [14] God then caused his servant to see
>   the staff of a watcher. ~Calvin

Comment: This would probably be a better question for [hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) But needs a little fix'em up either way.  Can you edit your question to include the Bible Quote and translation?  And why you find it isn't clear?

Comment: The specific quotation from Calvin would be useful, as also the full reference to 'at least one other'. Also it would be helpful if you could do some more of the work yourself, linking to the Hebrew (I suggest Biblehub or similar) to show your thesis regarding watcher/almond meaning. Are you suggesting that an Hebrew homonym is involved, perhaps ?

Comment: Your formatting was kind of hard to read. I re-formated this: please review and make sure I captured what you are trying to convey.

Comment: The question is easy to understand within the context of Jeremiah: it's a pivotal statement because God's next statement is irreversible judgement on Jerusalem. Therefore its meaning must have been clear to the readers and listeners. The question is how did they understand it.

Comment: Not just Almond but a 'rod' of Almond which has much to say about 'striking' and 'guiding'.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have always found this passage to be very powerful imagery indeed.

[Calvins commentary](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/calvin/jeremiah/1.htm):

> The word sqr, shaked, an almond, is derived from the verb, sqr, shakad, to watch; and it has been thought that this tree is so called, because it brings forth fruit earlier than other trees; for almonds, as it is well known, flower even in winter, and in the coldest seasons.

Calvin has three ideas on this passage. Calvin's first idea, which is probably not from Calvin because its extremely well-known, is almond blossom is the first bloom  of the new year. It occurs in the winter months, this being January to March. Therefore its imagery is 'ever watching', because its blossom is symbolic of the life of the tree and that is active from the start of the year. That would fit with the theme of the book of Jeremiah. In particular it fits with the next sentence ...

> <sup>12</sup> The Lord said to me, “You have seen correctly, for I am watching to see that my word is fulfilled.”

Calvin's second idea in this theme is the almond tree fruits much earlier than other trees. Thats more difficult to square with Jeremiah who prophesied exile was inevitable (Jer 1:14) and return from exile would not be quick.

Calvin's key idea is the grammatical context, almond and watching are based on the same root word. Double word meaning were common with the major prophets, e.g. Isaiah's suffering servant (Jesus) was buried "with the rich and with the wicked in his death" (Isaiah 53:9). "Rich" at this time in Hebrew and "wicked" were considered comparable root words and emphasising the complete injustice of the fate of the suffering servant.

---

Generally, trees must have had major spiritual metaphoric meaning *per se* in the ancient world: tree of life, tree of good and evil (Genesis 2: 9), cedars of Lebanon symbolising strength and human power (Isaiah 2:13; 37:24), "sacred" oaks for pagan worship, probably Asherah (Isaiah 1:29) and of course the parable of the mustard seed growing into a mighty tree (Matthew 13:31-32).

For such a simple passage it resonates earthquaking power.

Answer (score 0):

Almond is correct.  It is a reference to the menorah made of one-piece of pure gold with cups shaped like almond flowers, buds, blossoms. (Exo 25:33-34)

The menorah symbolizes a number of things.

Bud God the Father
Blossom God the Son
Cup God the Spirit

66 parts of 66 books of the bible

Lit the Holy Place, the Tent of Meeting

> Thy word is a lamp unto my feet, and a light unto my path. Psalm 119:105

> To the law and to the testimony: if they speak not according to this word, it is because there is no light in them. Isa 8:20

The bible is the lamp lit with oil (Son and Spirit).

So, what do you see Jeremiah?  An almond branch.

Good, God will perform as He promised/spoke/prophesied.